# How to get tiff file's xResolution & yResolution with javascript

Tags: javascript

How to get tiff file's `xResolution` & `yResolution`  with javascript.

I used `tiff.js` and `jquery.exif.js` but seem can't read.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future endeavour at Stack overflow.Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community  -Thank you

Comment: Please, post your efforts, so we can find any errors.